# あるセレクタの直下かつ先頭というCSSセレクタはありますか？

Tags: html, css, html5

こちらのspanには適用させず、

```html
<div>テキスト<span>テスト1</span>テキスト<div>
```

こちらのspanには適用できるセレクタを探しています。

```html
<div><span>テスト2</span>テキスト<div>
```

divの直下かつ先頭（テキストを除く）という擬似クラス等はないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たぶんできないと思います。

HTMLは、[DOM; Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)で表現されますが、これは

- Document
- Node
- Element
- Attr

などで表現されます。
CSSセレクタでは、ElementやAttrは扱えますが、それ以外のNodeを扱うものは用意されていません。
ここで質問の例において、`<span>` Elementと兄弟になっている`テキスト`の部分はTextNodeと呼ばれ、ElementでもAttrでもありません。
このため、CSSセレクタではTextNodeの存在・不存在どちらも表現することはできないと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。TextNodeという名称および、CSSセレクタでは制御できない事がよく理解できました。

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla (Firefox) の拡張には [`:-moz-first-node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-first-node) という、ずばりの物が有るのですが、標準化の予定は無いとの事です。これの代替手段に触れた記述が見つからない所から見ても、標準の範囲では無理なのでしょう。